# Python function not returning true or false

Tags: python, function

This is a simple function that checks the values entered by the user and returns true if x is a multiple of y, if not it returns false. When I run the code, it prompts the user to enter a number for x and y but does not display whether it is true or false. What am I doing wrong?

```
def is_multiple(x, y):
    if (y % x) == 0:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

x = int(input("enter any number :"))
y = int(input("enter a multiple :"))
```

Comment: You never *call* the function.

Comment: (Also, your function returns `None`; it *writes* the string `True` or the string `False` to standard output.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to *call* the function after you get the arguments.

```
def is_multiple(x, y):
    if y % x == 0:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")


# Using different names to stress the difference between
# function parameters and function arguments.
n = int(input("enter any number :"))
m = int(input("enter a multiple :"))
is_multiple(n, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you have to call the function.

Add this at the end:

```
is_multiple(x, y)
```

You could make your function much more useful by doing this however:

```
def is_multiple(x, y):
if (y % x) == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False

x = int(input("enter any number :"))
y = int(input("enter a multiple :"))
print(is_multiple(x, y))
```

Now your function actually *returns* a value that you can use however you'd like. In this case, it is printing the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

call the function which you declared above

```
is_multiple(x,y)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).